# How do i construct a route without ViewContext in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to create a route from a utility class that doesn't have access to a ViewContext.

Is this possible? There doesnt seem to be any equivalent of `ViewContext.Current`

I've tried fishing around in all the constructors for Routing and HttpContext but can't quite get to what I want.

This is what I'm looking for - although this doesn't work because `RouteTable.Routes` is of type `RouteCollection` and not `RouteData`. So close - yet so far :-)

```
        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(HttpContext.Current, RouteTable.Routes);
        UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
        var urlString = url.RouteUrl(new {controller="DynamicImage", action="Button", text="Hello World"});
```

Note: RequestContest is of type System.Web.Routing.RequestContext and not HttpContext

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext);
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext, new RouteData()));
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATED:**

The previous is not correct (I've posted it from my memory). Try this instead (it works in one of my projects):

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData());
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
```

`new RouteData()` is using just only for `RequestContext` initialization and `new UrlHelper(requestContext)` actually calls `new UrlHelper(requestContext, RouteTable.Routes)`

Comment: i was surprised that that actually works. i'm just not yet sure what the implications of having an empty RouteData() object is. perhaps it uses the current route as a 'base' for the new route? anyone know?