# Link mvc3 views from web form user control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have an existing web forms web application. I want to make a slow transition over to mvc3. To make that happen, I'd like to able to from my old user control (System.Web.UI.UserControl) link in my new mvc3 content with Html.Action and Html.Render. Is it possible? Any hackish solution would do.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work for an `UrlHelper`; in your webform:

```
<% var requestContext = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(
       new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current),
       new System.Web.Routing.RouteData());
   var urlHelper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(requestContext); %>
```

I imagine the same should work for the `HtmlHelper`; otherwise just use the Url.RouteUrl method:

```
<a href="<%= urlHelper.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Controller", 
    action = "Action" }) %>">To the MVC app!</a>
```

For the record, I got it from the following answer: [Access HtmlHelpers from WebForm when using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274319/access-htmlhelpers-from-webform-when-using-asp-net-mvc/1274459#1274459)